# Spring Boot MongoDB default repository/template implementation and field projection

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I've just started using Spring Data MongoDB, and from the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/) it looks really nice. I have a question about the default query implementations so I'll know whether I need to write my own implementations.

Let's say that I have a lot of `Person` documents that contain loads of information—not only person "Name" but potentially megabytes of information like purchase history, travel dates, math homework, or whatever. (The specific information is irrelevant—let's just say it's a lot of extra fields.) But sometimes I want to just query a list of `Person.name`.

It looks like Spring Data MongoDB allows me to [select specific fields when querying](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.querying.field-selection), which is of course standard MongoDB [field projection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/). But if I just do a standard query using [`MongoTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template) or a [MongoDB reposistory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.repositories), will Spring Data MongoDB automatically do a field projection to MongoDB to query only the fields needed to construct the object? Or will it do a general query and only determine which fields are useful after the data is returned?

For example, let's say I have a DTO Java record like this:

```java
record PersonListItem(String name) {}
```

If I have a `PersonListItemRepository extends CrudRepository<PersonListItem, String>` and call `findAll()`, will Spring Data MongoDB by default query the documents and *all* their fields, or will it proactively see that it only needs `name` and include that field projection in the query, so that that MongoDB will only send back the information needed to construct a `PersonListItem`? What about if I use `MongoTemplate`? Do any of them proactively project fields? Or will I need to manually write such queries if I want efficient query and data transfer based on a subset of document fields?

Comment: Found this "In MongoDB, Projections are a way to fetch only the required fields of a document from a database. This reduces the amount of data that has to be transferred from database server to client and hence increases performance. With Spring Data MongoDB, projections can be used both with MongoTemplate and MongoRepository." From: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-projections-aggregations

Answer (score 0):

Both `MongoRepository` and `MongoTemplate`, will fetch the whole document and then populate the class objects. You'll have to specify projections manually. For `MongoRepository`, it can be done like this:

```
@Query(value="{ 'name' : ?0 }", fields="{ 'name' : 1}")
List<PersonListItem> findByThePersonsName(String name);
```

Notice the fields parameter specifying the projected fields here.

For `MongoTemplate` this should work:

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("name").is(name));
query.fields().include("name");
List<PersonListItem> john = mongoTemplate.find(query, User.class);
```